# RC4 - Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Attempting to complete a tutorial which is bogged down by the old router. I have updated the code to use the new router but I can't get routerLink to be understood. Grateful for assistance.

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarTopComponent} from './components/navbar-top/navbar-top.component';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import {AboutComponent} from './components/about/about.component';
import {SearchComponent} from './components/search/search.component';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,NavbarTopComponent,SearchComponent]

})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import {AboutComponent} from './components/about/about.component';
import {SearchComponent} from './components/search/search.component';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**app.component.html**

```
<navbar-top></navbar-top>
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
</div>
```

**navbar-top.component.html**

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function(global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',

    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];

  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

  // No umd for router yet
  packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

**navbar-top.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'navbar-top',
    templateUrl: 'navbar-top.component.html'
})
export class NavbarTopComponent { }
```

Comment: The links are in `app.component.html`? Maybe an issue with your configuration. Purging `node_modules` and reinstall might be worth a try. Can you also please post your systemjs config?

Comment: Looks everything almost okay.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - have updated the question.

Comment: now you also have to show us `nav-top.component.ts` problem is there.

Comment: Updated again - I fear I am about to feel stupid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router'; //<-------- required

@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'navbar-top',
    templateUrl: 'navbar-top.component.html',

    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]  //<-------required

})
export class NavbarTopComponent { }
```

Comment: Important to note that this answer is no longer valid. "Directives" is no longer required on components, and ROUTER_DIRECTIVES no longer exists as of Angular 2 final